# Amazon Linux AMI with MongoDB installed - service FAILED to start

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

I have mongodb installed on a new Amazon Linux AMI after implementing the guide [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat-centos-or-fedora-linux/). When running "service mongod start" though, I just get a Starting mongod FAILED message.  Nothing else.  Blank log file also.

service mongod stop yields a FAILED also.

service mongod status yields "mongod is stopped"

Any thoughts or next steps?

Comment: does the `mongod` user have write permissions to the log directory? Does it have read permissions to `mongod.conf`?

Comment: Yes it does, Pete. Definitely one of the first things I verified.

Comment: I installed from this one a hundred times, so I know it works: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/platforms/amazon-ec2/. I skip the part about multiple drives, but I just do it for testing, for deployment I would follow those instructions as closely as possible. I am going to compare the instructions from my link to the instructions in your link to find the difference. It may require a documentation update.

Comment: I'm going to try from a fresh server also. Anything you find appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem with my master mongodb instance. I have a replica set of 3 instances on EC2 and I had the same problem after one reboot that we needed for it, mongod simply failed to start.

First thing I did, was changed the ownership of the log file that is set up in the mongod.conf:

`sudo chown mongod:mongod <LOG FILE>`

After this I tried only `sudo mongod` and this will log the problem why the service won't start in the log file.

Mine appeared to be some ownership issues with the WiredTiger conf files in the dbPath directory (were set to root ownership instead to mongod user)

Answer (score 0):

What I do in that case is use

```
sudo killall mongod
```

and after that it starts ok. My suspicion is that there is a running instance and that's why it fails to start.